# Can I use C++ classes and class objects inside POSIX thread also function calls

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

I like to know can I use C++ programming concepts in threads from `pthread.h` is there any limitation, if yes then what would that be. any information about documentation of C++ in Posix threads I am looking for

Comment: Do you really need to use Pthreads when [C++ has threads built-in](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)? You can use PThreads as you would in C, but it's kind of messy by comparison.

Comment: @tadman, C has builtin threads too. But hear pthreads provides a better interface. No idea how they compare to C++ threads.

Comment: Yes, the language in which a function is written is of no relevance. It's all machine code when it executes. The function would have to obey C calling conventions, though. I don't know if you need to do anything to ensure that.

Comment: @ikegami I guess [this happened](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) but that doesn't seem like fun. C++ threads are actually pretty nice, and play a lot better with things like C++ lambdas and `std::function`.

Comment: You would definitely want to use C++ threads over pthreads if you have that choice.  C++ threads use the same patterns and essentially the same primitive objects, but are much cleaner to use.

Comment: C11 threads don't work well with C++ lambdas & `std::function`?? *Surprised*.

Comment: @P.P I never had any problem, but it's 2021. Hopefully he's not using a 10-year-old compiler.

Answer (score 0):

C++ was designed to interoperate with C, so you can use freely all the functions from the standard C library in C++.  The only limitation is that the development has to be made in C++.  C++ can use C functions with minor or no modification at all, but the reverse is not true: C can only use C functions.  In order to be able to include C++ code, you must first wrap the C++ code into

```
extern "C"
```

wrapper functions, and limit your use to only those functions inside, and link your program as a C++ program (this is necessary to initialize all the global instances that your program can have, calling the constructors appropiately before calling `main()`)